# UICollectionView not re-displaying supplementary views scrolled off screen when keyboard is visible

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass, which specifies supplementary views around cells and at the start and end of a section. For the purpose of this question, I've created a [sample project](https://github.com/zacwest/collection-view-reuse-keyboard) which has a distilled version of my layout subclass.  I've also created [a video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbawvvz3hgdl5vj/reuse_problem.mov) which demonstrates visually the problem I'm about to describe.

The sample project lays out things as such (`[0, 1]` = section `0` item `1`):

- `[0, 0]` A "section"-level supplementary view of type `HEYCollectionViewElementKindHeaderA`
- `[0, 0]` An "item"-level supplementary view of type `HEYCollectionViewElementKindCellA`
- `[0, 0]` A cell for this index path.
- `[0, 1]` Another CellA variety
- `[0, 1]` A cell for this index path.
- etc.

In the sample project, there are a few additional headers that I've commented out in the `HEYCollectionViewLayout` class. If you uncomment them, you can see even more views that aren't reused correctly.

All of the header views have a `UITextField` inside, though I am able to reproduce this issue with both a `UITextView` and also my own `UIView` which has an `inputView` set and becomes first responder. When the keyboard is active on the text field in the `CellA [0, 0]` element and you scroll the supplementary views above it off-screen and then back on, the views are not re-added to the collection view.

In my investigations, I've found that the `UICollectionReusableView` subclasses are placed into the reuse queue and show up as `hidden=YES` in the view hierarchy, as expected when awaiting reuse. When the keyboard is not active, and I scroll the elements back on, the same instance of the class that was shown before will be reused and displayed onto the screen.

I have tried having the `UICollectionViewLayout` ask for a relayout on each bounds change (by returning `YES` from `-shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:`); this has no effect and the elements still end up hidden.

I've been unable to find any other reports of this issue on the internet, but I've reproduced it on the iOS simulator 7.1 in Xcode 5.1.1, and on an iPod Touch running iOS 7.1.2.

---

I've updated the repo above with a possible workaround:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    BOOL didResign = [super resignFirstResponder];

    if (didResign) {
        // This works around http://stackoverflow.com/q/25189751/551420

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
        });
    }

    return didResign;
}
```

I believe the issue is some kind of broken internal state in `UICollectionView` which is fixed by forcing an update whenever the `UICollectionViewController` resigns first responder (because a child becomes first responder).

This doesn't seem like the right solution, so I'm not marking it as an answer, but in case somebody else encounters the problem, this is how I'm currently trying to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely seems to me to be some kind of internal state dealing with the first responder that's getting broken.

One workaround I've found is to make each supplementary view's index path unique by adding an extra index:

```
- (void)prepareLayout {
    [super prepareLayout];

    [self.supplementaryViewAttributes removeAllObjects];
    [self.cellAttributes removeAllObjects];

    CGFloat minimumY = 0;

    for (NSInteger sectionIdx = 0; sectionIdx < self.collectionView.numberOfSections; sectionIdx++) {
        NSIndexPath *sectionIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:sectionIdx];

        NSInteger suppViewIdx = 0;
        NSIndexPath *suppIndexPath = [sectionIndexPath indexPathByAddingIndex:suppViewIdx];
        suppViewIdx++;

        [self newAttributesForSupplementaryViewAtIndexPath:suppIndexPath
                                                      kind:HEYCollectionViewElementKindHeaderA
                                                    height:HEYCollectionViewHeaderHeight
                                                  minimumY:&minimumY];

        suppIndexPath = [sectionIndexPath indexPathByAddingIndex:suppViewIdx];
        suppViewIdx++;

        [self newAttributesForSupplementaryViewAtIndexPath:suppIndexPath
                                                      kind:HEYCollectionViewElementKindHeaderB
                                                    height:HEYCollectionViewHeaderHeight
                                                  minimumY:&minimumY];

        for (NSInteger itemIdx = 0; itemIdx < [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:sectionIdx]; itemIdx++) {
            NSIndexPath *itemIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:itemIdx inSection:sectionIdx];

            suppIndexPath = [itemIndexPath indexPathByAddingIndex:suppViewIdx];
            suppViewIdx++;

            [self newAttributesForSupplementaryViewAtIndexPath:suppIndexPath
                                                          kind:HEYCollectionViewElementKindCellA
                                                        height:HEYCollectionViewCellHeight
                                                      minimumY:&minimumY];

            suppIndexPath = [itemIndexPath indexPathByAddingIndex:suppViewIdx];
            suppViewIdx++;

            [self newAttributesForSupplementaryViewAtIndexPath:suppIndexPath
                                                          kind:HEYCollectionViewElementKindCellB
                                                        height:HEYCollectionViewCellHeight
                                                      minimumY:&minimumY];

            [self newAttributesForCellAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath minimumY:&minimumY];
        }
    }
}
```

If this is an internal bug, then this seems like a decent workaround to me since it does not alter your index paths' `section` or `item` values, and it also means you don't have to subclass `UICollectionView` to force it to update when it resigns first responder.

However, if you are currently `compare:`-ing or testing for equality on index paths (using `isEqual:` for example), then this workaround could possibly break that. You'd have to instead make sure to only compare the `section` and `item` to keep the same functionality.